# How do I make nv-file-select uploader required Angular

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I need to make file uploader field required with angular according to a condition.

```
<input ng-hide="true" type="file" id="fileUploader" name="attachement" nv-file-select uploader="uploader"/>
```

If the condition is true, make this input mandatory.

Comment: Have you tried using the ```ng-required``` input?

Comment: Yes, a message is displayed but i can validate the form!